# is_numeric_array() is missing

Tags: php, php5, array

I found that in PHP (or I probably can't find it) a proper `is_numeric_array($array)` function is missing. So I created one. The problem is that I don't think it's great and I don't know how to improve it.

Any suggestion?

**My first function**

```
function is_numeric_array($array)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $a => $b) { if (is_int($a)) { ++$i; } }
    if (count($array) === $i) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

is_numeric_array(array(0,0,0,0,0)); // true
is_numeric_array(array('str' => 1, 'str2' => 2, 'str3' => 3)); // false
```

**Example**

As asked, I provide an example on how this could be any useful.

```
function is_numeric_array($array)
{
    # Code below
}

function someFunction($array)
{
    if (is_numeric_array($array))
    {
        $query = $array[0];
        $param = $array[1];
        $fetch = $array[2];
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $array['query'];
        $param = $array['param'];
        $fetch = $array['fetch'];
    }

    # Do your sql/pdo stuff here
}

# This use is the same of ...
someFunction(array(
    'PDO SQL STATEMENT', 
    array('param1' => 1, 'param2' => 2, 'param3' => 3),
    true
));

# ... this one.
someFunction(array(
    'query' => 'PDO SQL STATEMENT',
    'param' => array('param1' => 1, 'param2' => 2, 'param3' => 3),
    'fetch' => true
));

# To choose one form instead of the other is coder's decision
# Also I know it is useless but I was just wondering why anybody actually looked forward this function
```

Comment: Im just curious, can you provide a use case for this?

Comment: Done, hope you like it.

Comment: They're all bad =) This is the only right one: https://gist.github.com/1272230

Comment: The more I read the more confused I became; You seem to determine if an array is associative or not, Whereas I read this topic as "determine if all array values are numeric/integers". A Straightforward approach to an is_assoc check is exemplified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/173479/1695680

Comment: Apologies, after further consideration the linked answer is not so reliable; You'd actually want to modify the next answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254008/1695680 to use 'is_int' instead of 'is_string'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of using a counter to count the keys for which the condition is true, you could just return false as soon as you find a key which is not an int and return true if the loop reaches its end without finding such a key:

```
foreach ($array as $a => $b) {
    if (!is_int($a)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

This has the benefit that it short-circuits (i.e. it stops iterating once it finds a key that is not an int) and gets rid of the counter.

Comment: How about `array_fill(3, 5, 0)`? Do you consider that a numeric array?

Comment: Instead of using is_int($a) use ($a !== (int) $a) and it will be 10x faster.

Answer (score 14):

Improving a little on @sepp2k answer(+1) (removing the "unused variable warning" some tools will spit out):

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $a)) {
    if (!is_int($a)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

If you want to check if it's an linear array:

```
return array_merge($array) === $array;
```

or @RobertPitt's solution :) (Also +1 there)

### But my main point:

Why do you need this, i've never had use for something like this and it **might** be that the solution is change and API design flaw or data structure flaw somewhere ? Doesn't have too, but might.

### Response to OPs comment:

I'm building a db method for queries that needs of a 3 keys array. In case the array is Numeric the order must be: statement, parameters, fetch. In case it's not, so the coder is specifying the key string, the order can be different and two out of three required parameters could be empty.

Ok then let my try to do that specif to your requirements :)

```
my_db_function(
    array("myquery", array("params", "..."), "myfetchmode")
);
// or 
my_db_function(
    array("params" => "myquery", "fetchmode" => "myfetchmode, "params" => array("myparams", "...) )
);
```

Maybe i misunderstood a little but it should get the point across how one could build that with a different check :)

```
function my_db_fuction($statement) {

    if(isset($statement["query"])) { // Assoc 'Mode'
        $query = $statement["query"];
        if(isset($statement["params"])) { $params = $statement["params"]; } 
        else { $params = array(); }
        if(isset($statement["fetchmode"])) { $fetchmode = $statement["fetchmode"]; }
        else { $fetchmode = "select"; // optional param, default value here

    } else if(isset($statement[0]) { // Linear Array Mode

        $query = $statement[0];
        if(isset($statement[1])) { $params = $statement[1]; } 
        else { $params = array(); }
        if(isset($statement[2])) { $fetchmode = $statement[2]; }
        else { $fetchmode = "select"; // optional param, default value here

    } else {
         // Error, misformed format
    }
    // Now we got our 3 variables :)
}
```

That is still a pretty big code block but i didn't want to shorten it and risk worse readabilty.

What i would do with that is create a my_db_stuff_param_helper($aParams) that will always return an array containing the 3 keys filled with the real values (or defaults if nothing was passed)

```
  function my_db_fuction($statement) {
      $statement = my_db_parse_params($statement);
      // now e.g. $statement["query"] will always be there
  }
```

something along those lines "feels" (subjective, i know) better than building a generic function to do the key checking. (I guess it's  **isset($statement["query"])** instead of **is_numeric_array** what i boilds down to :)

Comment: I need of it because i'm creating a method that, based on how it is written, must behave different ways.

Comment: You are doing something that forces you to do something and because of that you need this method. I'm saying maybe if you do something different you don't need that. Sry i got no idea how i could make myself clearer but i read your answers as "I need this because i need this" and i'm just suggesting that maybe you don't :) And since this is codereview and not SO i though i mention it and don't just provide a code snippet with the (for me at least) obvious answer :)

Comment: I got what you are saying. I'm building a db method for queries that needs of a 3 keys array. In case the array is Numeric the order must be: statement, parameters, fetch. In case it's not, so the coder is specifying the key string, the order can be different and two out of three required parameters could be empty. I know it's strange and I'm going to edit it, but I was just wondering if a proper function doesn't exist.

Comment: Edited my answer in response, might be a bit overblown :)

Comment: Didn't thought about this method. Thanks for providing it. But, let's face it, PHP has a lot of useless functions, why don't put `is_numeric_array()` into the core? <sarcasm> Look at that `eval()` function, isn't my `is_numeric_array()` function way more helpfull? </sarcasm>

Answer (score 6):

At first I didn't realise you wanted to check see if the keys are integers. If the reason you're doing this is to make sure the keys are 0,1,2,3,4.. etc as an indexed array and not an associative array, then you could use this:

```
function is_numeric_array($arr)
{
    return array_keys($arr) === range(0,(count($arr)-1));
}

/*
    * Tests
*/
var_dump(is_numeric_array(array('a', 'b', 'c'))); // true
var_dump(is_numeric_array(array("0" => 'a', "1" => 'b', "2" => 'c'))); // true
var_dump(is_numeric_array(array("1" => 'a', "0" => 'b', "2" => 'c'))); // false
var_dump(is_numeric_array(array("a" => 'a', "b" => 'b', "c" => 'c'))); // false
```

Benchmark results as requested:

Here's the code used to test the execution:

```
$array = array();
for($i=0;$i<=500000;$i++)
{
    $array[] = "some_string";
}

$m_initial = memory_get_usage();
is_numeric_array($array);
$increase = memory_get_usage() - $m_initial;
```

As you can see from the above, I tested with a linear array that had 500K strings:

The value of `$increase` showed **65032** (which is in bytes). If we converted to K**B** this is around 64 rounded up. The result in KB shows **63.507**, which in my opinion is ok.

Comment: It actually checks only values, not keys. Am i wrong?

Comment: added the `$key` to that.

Comment: `array_filter`'s callback only takes array values as an argument. You'd need to fetch `array_keys` first, and filter that.

Comment: yea is scrapped it, I was a little in-consistence and should of done my research.

Comment: Well, i'd like that the second example returns false since you, as coder, defined a specific key.

Comment: Charlie, Please elaborate, your comment has got me all confused :)

Comment: Still no good: `var_dump(is_numeric_array(array(1 => 'a', 'b', 'c')));`

Comment: The second example is not a numeric array since the keys are strings. I'd like the second example to return false.

Comment: Charlie, as the index of the second example is in numeric order, the strings are automatically converted to *ints* and stored as an enumerable array, this is why the the third example returns false as there in the order of `1`,`0`,`2` and not `0`,`1`,`2`. if this is the case then it seems like you need to change the way your method requires the arrays to be.

Comment: I'd love to see a large array passed in and watch memory usage... :-D

Comment: recheck the posts for some benchmark results

Answer (score 5):

This will drop out as soon as an element is found that is not an int, making the function more efficient for large arrays.

```
function is_numeric_array($array) {
   foreach ($array as $a=>$b) {
      if (!is_int($a)) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing as his code does it? Unless I'm missing something this checks whether the values are ints, not the keys. Also the code will cause an error if the keys aren't ints.

Comment: Also it's `return $i` instead of `return $1`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how `count` works, but it likely rewalks the array, causing you to go over it twice.

Comment: ...also no stop condition on while loop. Changed.

Comment: And look at that - all that great thinking and someone else posted the same thing already :)

Comment: I would also try to `krsort($array,SORT_STRING);` first. This should move most non-numeric keys to the begining of the array. One would need to benchmark if it gives any increase in performance.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's a shot for consistency and proper naming conventions (Since `numeric` and `int` mean different things all together, there's little point calling one the other...):

```
function isNumericArray(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $a => $b) {
        if (!is_numeric($a)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isIntArray(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $a => $b) {
        if (!is_int($a)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, for a more OO approach, I'd build a filteriterator:

```
class NumericFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return is_numeric(parent::current());
    }
}

class IntFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return is_int(parent::current());
    }
}
```

Then, if you just want to iterate over the integer, just do `$it = new IntFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));`.  If you want to verify, you can do:

```
$it = new IntFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
if ($array != iterator_to_array($it)) {
    //Has a non-int element
}
```

Comment: +1 for the difference and the `FilterIterator`. Only thing that could be improved is to only check the array values. No need to run over the whole array.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be way more efficient:

```
function is_numeric_array($array)
{
    $array = array_keys($array);

    if ($array === array_filter($array, 'is_int'))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

I just noticed what you're really trying to do is not check if all the keys in an array are integers but rather if the array is indexed (non-associative), for this use `array_values()` does the trick:

```
function is_numeric_array($array)
{
    return ($array === array_values($array));
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted solution! array_values FTW!

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually trying to determine whether it's a sequential integer array rather than associative, i.e. something that json_encode would make an array vs an object, this is probably the fastest way to to do so:

```
function is_normal_array($arr) {
    $c = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        if (!isset($arr[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

...of course the fastest code is code you never run, so consider whether you really, really need to do this, and only use it where you do.

Comment: This should be faster than the foreach solutions others have posted, but the algorithms don't agree perfectly. The foreach solutions return true for array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 3 => 'd') whereas mine returns false.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but if you're looking for a shorter but still elegant solution, use this:

```
return array_values($array) === $array
```

You could even use it as condition since it's pretty short too. Cheers